# How to plot a mathematical equation in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a mathematical function
`y = x^3 + sin(x)` which I calculated using the below formular

```
np.random.seed(10)
x = np.random.random(20)
def calculate(x):
    cube_x = np.power(x,3)
    sin_x = np.sin(x)
    y = cube_x + sin_x
    
    return y
```

and I created a plot for the above equation

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (14, 8))
##Plot y = x^3 + sin(x)
y = calculate(x)
##plt.plot(x, y, 'b', label = '$x^3$ + $\sin$ $(x)$')
# Add features to our figure
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True, linestyle =':')
plt.xlim([0, 2])
plt.ylim([0, 2])
plt.title("Plot of  y = $x^3$ + $\sin$ $(x)$ ")
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')
# Show plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

I am **not sure** the above graph is correct. Please I need your assistance to know if I am getting the desired graph for the above function.

Comment: i think `numpy.linspace` is a more appropriate function to use to define `x`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort your random array in order to generate the plot correcty. You can use:

```py
x = np.sort(np.random.random(20))
```

You can also use `plt.scatter()` instead of `plt.plot()`, so you don't have to sort the `x` array.

Answer (score 1):

Like *JMA* said, you should to sort *x* first. If you had plotted your original data as a scatter, it would look fine:

[image: scatter]

However, if you were in a situation where you could not sort your input data prior to evaluating the function *y*, you can use `np.argsort`. Say you already have *x* and *y* computed and needed to sort *x* and *y* based on the order of *x* alone (e.g. *y* is not monotonic), you would use the following lines.

```
idx = np.argsort(x)
x, y = x[idx], y[idx]
```

and you plot would look like:

[image: correct]